# Django: How can I access data of a model through another model?

Tags: django, model

I have a post model and I want the category attribute to be a set of options.  I also want to be able to change the options dynamically.  I'm currently using a many to many relationship so whenever a post is made, a category must be selected and I can edit the choices for each category this way.  But I can't figure out how to access that chosen category option for a post.

For example, I can made post with title "apple" and choose category name "food", then I can make a post titled "rose" and category name "flower".  Then I can display the title of each post on a template BUT I can't display or figure out how to store/access the category name.

Here is are my models

```
    class Category(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    class Post(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
        category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

As is now, I can go on admin and make a post with a title and choose a category I've made from a list for that post.

Here's my view and template

```
    def index(request):
        posts = Post.objects.order_by("-created")
        return render(request,'posts/index.html', {'posts':posts,'categories':categories})


    {% for post in posts %}

            {{ post.title }} | of {{  post.category }}

    {% endfor %}
```

the post.category doesn't show the category but rather

How can I display the category name for a post?  Do I need to set this up differently?  If you know of a way for me to do this, please let me know what you think.  I thought a ManyToMany relationship was the way to go but perhaps not

Answer (score 0):

use `{{  post.category.name }}`
In your templates.
Using many to one relations seems more suited.
Use it like this.

```
  class Category(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    class Post(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
        category = models.ForeignKeyField('Category')
```

If you want to keep the manytomany relationship you can do:

```
{% for post in posts %}

      {{ post.title }} | of 
      {% for category in post.category_set %}
        {{  category.name }}
      {% endfor%}
{% endfor %}
```